# Broken libgcrypt11 dependency

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dependencies, libgcrypt

I've run a casual `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` command. The process completed (with an error): `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcrypt11 : Breaks: libgcrypt11:i386 (!= 1.5.0-3ubuntu0.3) but 1.5.0-3ubuntu0.4 is installed
 libgcrypt11:i386 : Breaks: libgcrypt11 (!= 1.5.0-3ubuntu0.4) but 1.5.0-3ubuntu0.3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f..
```

I tried to run `apt-get -f install`, but it gave an error too:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgcrypt11
Suggested packages:
  rng-tools
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libxslt1.1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgcrypt11
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 77 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/282 kB of archives.
After this operation, 477 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 1288453 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libxslt1.1:i386 ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 fork failed: Cannot allocate memory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)'.
```

I tried to run `dpkg --configure -a`, but there was another pitfall:

```
dpkg: error processing libgcrypt11 (--configure):
 libgcrypt11:amd64 1.5.0-3ubuntu0.3 cannot be configured because libgcrypt11:i386 is in a different version (1.5.0-3ubuntu0.4)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcrypt11
```

So I'm stuck with updates. I tried to remove libgcrypt with aptitude, but I ran into the same issue. I am completely clueless. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this a virtual machine? it appears you are out of memory.

Comment: No. Maybe I had too many chrome tabs open. Closed everything else, tried again, same issue, no fork failure.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are seeing "fork failed: Cannot allocate memory" I'm guessing you have run out of memory or a related resource.  Try closing you browser and other memory hungry applications before you reattempt.  A reboot would also help.

Comment: Closed everything. Ran `apt-get upgrade`. Still the same issues.